# How to scroll text input in React Native as content get bigger?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I currently have an auto-growing text input field that will expand to a certain clamped height.

The issue is that once the text input has grown to its max size, the content that I write gets pushed under the container. See attached images

Before Issue:

[Expanded view, before issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb1oM.png)

Post Issue:

[Cursor has disappeared from view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i94J7.jpg)

I though about having the Text Input scroll to the end, but I haven't found any documentation or API that allows me to `scrollTo` end of the input. (Similar to `ScrollView`)

The final functionality is that of a chat application messaging box.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

function clamp(num, min, max) {
      return num <= min ? min : num >= max ? max : num;
}

class AutogrowTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {'contentHeight': props.minHeight};

    this.resize = this.resize.bind(this);
}

render() {
    let height = clamp(this.state.contentHeight, this.props.minHeight, this.props.maxHeight) + 20;
    let inputStyle = {height: height, flex: 0};

    return (
        <TextInput
            {...this.props}
            style={[this.props.style, inputStyle]}
            onContentSizeChange={this.resize}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
    );
}

resize(event) {
    this.setState({
        'contentHeight': event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
    });
    }
}

export default AutogrowTextInput;
```

Instantiation of Element.

```
    return (
    <View style={style.footer}>
        <TouchableIcon
            onPress={this._attach}
            icon="add"
            color="#000"
        />
        <AutogrowTextInput
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            style={style.input}
            placeholder="Send Message"
            value={message}
            onChangeText={this._changeText}
            autoFocus={false}
            multiline={true}
            minHeight={30}
            maxHeight={100}
        />
        {attachmentComps}
        <TouchableIcon
            disabled={sending || isEmpty}
            onPress={this._sendMessage}
            icon="send"
            color="#000"
        />
    </View>
);
```

Styling:

```
footer: {
    borderTopWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    paddingVertical: 4,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    flex: 0
},
input: {flexGrow: 1, fontSize: 16, paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 1},
attachmentContainer: {marginHorizontal: 4},
attachment: {height: 40, width: 40, borderRadius: 2},
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Cannot post images in line because of lack of reputation.

Comment: Hey @Johnnie Tirado!  Is auto-growing text input field you used a regular TextInput for react-native ?

Comment: @A-J-A, correct, I have created a component that auto-grows the container that has the TextInput inside of it. My issue comes when the Container reached the max height set by the props and the TextInput uses its native scroll view functionality. It does not automatically scroll to the end of the input.

Comment: I have a recomendation you can make the textinput it self automatically grow as you type and not the container it self that way it will fix your problem. sounds good ?

Comment: @A-J-A Added the code, I just tried doing that, but getting the same behavior. Let me know if there is something that stands out. Thanks.

Comment: can you comment out clamp function and check if its the problem ?

Comment: and remove flex = 0

Comment: Didn't work, cursor and text keeps on hiding and it does not scroll to end of line.

Comment: I guess it's a style thing can you add where are you placing this text input with the styles ?

Comment: Added all the code, thanks again for helping.

Comment: Don't even mention it ! , okay now you have to go by divide and conquer, start removing flex: 0 and all vertical resctrictions (paddingVertical etc ..)